# Javascript not working at all

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and can't figure out why no script is working in either Firefox or IE. I'm working with Notepad++ and after my external .js file didn't work I made a simple script that isn't working either:

This is the end of my html.

```html
<div id="form1">
 <form>
  <textarea name="boxtext" id="textarea1" rows="10" colums="30">
   maximum 300 characters
  </textarea>
  <button type="button" id="submit1" onclick="myFunction()">submit this</button>
 </form>
</div>
<div id="forTheBoxes"></div>
<div id="footer">Copyright Jesper Hodge</div>

<script>myFunction() {window.alert("ok!")}</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you need to declare `myFunction` as a function.

Comment: Open dev console on chrome/firefox(F12 is the default). Shows the errors.

Comment: Simply change the line <script>myFunction() {window.alert("ok!")}</script> to this: <script>function myFunction() {window.alert("ok!")}</script> and you should be good to go. As recommended, use Dev Tool bar or Firefox to see js errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make this changes:

```
function myFunction() {
  window.alert("ok!");
}
```

Or

```
var myFunction=function () {
  window.alert("ok!");
}
```

Comment: Why the double braces?

Comment: sorry it was a mistake .My bad.

Comment: sorry for that stupid error. Yes it's working now. I guess my external .js file has similar Problems. Will check everything...

Answer (score 0):

2 things I see.  The word function is missing where you declare your function.

```
<script>function myFunction() {window.alert("ok!")}</script>
```

And your script it in a bad place.  Try putting it in `<head>` area.

Comment: Position of Script Tag doesn't matter. It can placed inside body as well, further subjected to requirements

Answer (score 0):

This should be work:

1) Declare function myFunction

2) Insert your external js file in your html header

3) Handle event onclick button in html

```js
 
      function myFunction() {
        alert("ok!"); 
     }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <script type="javascript/text" src="/yourJsSourceFile"></script>
  </head>
<body>
    <div id="form1">
            <form>
                <textarea name="boxtext" id="textarea1" rows="10" colums="30">
                    maximum 300 characters
                </textarea>
                <button type="button" id="submit1" onclick="myFunction()">submit this</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="forTheBoxes"></div>
        <div id="footer">Copyright Jesper Hodge</div>

        
        </body>

     </html>
```

Comment: Try to give them some explanation for the problem then just giving them solution to their answers